# Mysterious grey rectangles on notification panel

Tags: malware, virus

Got a new Nokia 5.4 that has just recently been updated to Android 11 with no 3rd-party apps installed except Kaspersky. However, I've been noticing a rather strange behaviour where there seems to be an almost invisible app running in the background. Dragging down the notifications (one level down, not all the way) and there seems to be some sort of app/icon when I tap the area.

Attached are screenshots so it's clearer.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Run a virus scan but nothing shows up. Whatever it is, it seems to have been on the phone before unboxing and first boot.

To clarify, this behavior has been there even before I installed anything on the phone. Spoke to Nokia support and they said it's not something they're aware of and suggested I report it as a bug. I've asked this question in Nokia's community forum to see if it's something that's present on all Nokia 5.4 models.

Wanted to get more thoughts if this is some spyware on the phone, which I highly suspect it is, and how do I remove it.

Any idea what it is? Is this some embedded spyware?

Comment: Let me summarize: you have no indication that this is actually spyware - all you have that it looks strange. You have the statement from Nokia that it is not spyware and you should report it is a bug. The AV you've tried does not find anything either. Yet you still believe this spyware - still only because it looks strange. Why should spyware look strange in the first place?

Comment: That's right, it does seem strange, and this has been present on the phone since Android 10 before the Android 11 update. Spoke to Nokia customer support and they didn't say it wasn't spyware. They just said they don't know what it is, and that it isn't typical behaviour. Hence, why I suspect it's spyware. Might just be a bug, but I've been facing persistent intrusions into my system both on my desktop and phones this past few months, which is why I'm more suspicious of this.

Comment: @robert The OP mentions that the behavior has already been observed prior to unboxing and a software update, so this is likely not the issue. Has anyone else faced the same issue on the same model or another Android device? Could be a poorly executed RAT or a frame draw issue if it's just a software bug.

Comment: I recommend you a factory reset

Comment: It's more of a bug with Notification UI than a spyware.